# How to conceptualize multiple callbacks, a.k.a. how do you think through code like this?

Tags: javascript, callback

For example, take this code (source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
// --file.js--
function getJSON(url, callback) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () { 
    callback(this.responseText) 
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
}

export function getUsefulContents(url, callback) {
  getJSON(url, data => callback(JSON.parse(data)));
}

// --main.js--
import { getUsefulContents } from 'file';
getUsefulContents('http://www.example.com', data => {
  doSomethingUseful(data);
});
```

I often come across a situation where I need to build something like this, or read it, and Im always so slow at it, so, is there a better way to conceptualize this pattern?

Heres my thought process currently (how I read the above) :

Ok, we have 2 files, one is getting a function imported from the other. (easy peasy)

The imported function is getting called, and passed a URL and callback function. (easy peasy lemon squeezy). This callback function takes 1 parameter ('data') and passes it to doSomethingUseful(data). (I believe were blocking at this point)

In file.js, getUsefulContents was called and passed the URL and callback.

getJSON is called, and passed the URL and a callback... Did everything just pass right through getUsefulContents? Why do we need it? (Confused back and forth)

...Ok whatever, getJSON now has the URL and callback. It creates a xhr object, reacts to an onload event by calling the callback (finally!) passing this.responseText to it (thats the data).

the callback runs, which runs doSomethingUseful(data) and were done.

This takes me quite a while to analyze on a regular basis. Are there any conceptual tricks or better ways to analyze this?

Answer (score -1):

Not really any tricks to conceptualizing it all together, but that goes against one of the main tricks we use as programmers.

That trick is to break the program down into functions to hide what they're doing inside. Instead of trying to understand everything as one big long flow, just understand that `getUsefulContents()` gives you some useful contents. Don't worry about how it's doing it, unless you're working on changing `getUsefulContents()`.

In general, you can think of each function as a black box. You feed it `a`, it spits out `b`. That's as much as you usually need to understand about it (unless you're mucking around inside it).

If you need to understand the whole program in minute detail, it's going to take take to understand. It's a lot to understand. That's why we use functions at like we do.

With callbacks, it looks a little different, but it's still the same. For a function that accepts a callback, you give it `a` and something to call when it's done. It calls that something and spits out `b`. Beyond that, you don't usually need to worry about it.

Comment: Whoever down-voted, care to share why? [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) is a key way that programmers make programs more readable and understandable.

Comment: Sure. The question was how to understand something. Youre advocating not understanding something.  What you said would in no way help me to build a function like in my example code, which is what I asked for help with.